# trying to export database and have less tables when importing it

Tags: mysql, import, phpmyadmin, export

am trying to export a MySQL Database Through phpmyadmin but when i try to import it to another server i have less tables (normal has 52 and the imported has 35 or 34 )
tried every export settings and import tho

Comment: How did you export and import DB? via command line, phpmyadmin or another client?

Comment: Go to phpmyadmin then select the database where are the tables and click "SQL" tab and execute this command: `SHOW TABLES` and give me know whether the result shows only 35 tables or all tables.

Comment: 52 in the exporting server

Comment: I thought try it in the server where you imported the data

Comment: its less 
tried in 2 different servers

Comment: Did you try to export and import just `structure` and then `data`? In phpmyadmin click Export then in Export method `Custom` then in options check just Structure to export then import it. The same do with `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late reply. But I hope it can helpful for others too. I had same problem to import 4GB database. Here are what I did,

1. Simply run mysql.exe file and it is located under C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.17\bin. Or click wamp icon, then MySQL->MySQL console.
2. It prompts password. If no password, then enter. Or give your password, then enter.
3. use dbname;
4. source location of sql file with full path\sqlfile.sql
5. Hit enter key and watch whether rows affected.

I hope this helps!